# Laravel: Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (but no such user is used in the app)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've a Laravel application that works well but for some strange reason there is a lot of strange messages in log files:

> [2019-10-04 10:24:21] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access d     enied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /var/www/html/pzw_prod/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31, PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'l     ocalhost' (using password: NO) at /var/www/html/pzw_prod/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27)

The thing is, I'm not connecting to database with user named `forge`. My `.env` uses completely different logins. And, I repeat, everything works fine: communication with database works as expected. Data is being successfully read and written.

So... why this message in log files?

UPDATE:

`config('database')`

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.22 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> config('database')
=> [
     "default" => "mysql",
     "connections" => [
       "sqlite" => [
         "driver" => "sqlite",
         "url" => null,
         "database" => /* CENSORED */,
         "prefix" => "",
         "foreign_key_constraints" => true,
       ],
       "mysql" => [
         "driver" => "mysql",
         "url" => null,
         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
         "port" => "3306",
         "database" => /* CENSORED */,
         "username" => "prod_pzw",
         "password" => /* CENSORED */,
         "unix_socket" => "",
         "charset" => "utf8",
         "collation" => "utf8_unicode_ci",
         "prefix" => "",
         "prefix_indexes" => true,
         "strict" => true,
         "engine" => null,
         "options" => [],
       ],
       "pgsql" => [
         "driver" => "pgsql",
         "url" => null,
         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
         "port" => "3306",
         "database" => /* CENSORED */,
         "username" => "prod_pzw",
         "password" => /* CENSORED */,
         "charset" => "utf8",
         "prefix" => "",
         "prefix_indexes" => true,
         "schema" => "public",
         "sslmode" => "prefer",
       ],
       "sqlsrv" => [
         "driver" => "sqlsrv",
         "url" => null,
         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
         "port" => "3306",
         "database" => /* CENSORED */,
         "username" => "prod_pzw",
         "password" => /* CENSORED */,
         "charset" => "utf8",
         "prefix" => "",
         "prefix_indexes" => true,
       ],
     ],
     "migrations" => "migrations",
     "redis" => [
       "client" => "predis",
       "options" => [
         "cluster" => "predis",
         "prefix" => /* CENSORED */,
       ],
       "default" => [
         "url" => null,
         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
         "password" => null,
         "port" => "6379",
         "database" => 0,
       ],
       "cache" => [
         "url" => null,
         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
         "password" => null,
         "port" => "6379",
         "database" => 1,
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

UPDATE 2:

It seems that 'forge' is some kind of default login. It seems that sometimes Laravel is not using values from `.env`. How can I debug this?

```
$ cat config/database.php | grep -B 5 forge
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
--
        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
--
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
```

Comment: go to artisan tinker, write `config('database')` and paste here (edit your question) the output. (sanitize any passwords for security reasons)

Comment: @EliasSoares, I've updated my question with output from `config('database')`

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: @cbaconnier, no, because I wasn't caching configuration (and cache is empty, I've checked).

Comment: I just ran into this after a Laravel update. It seems that the name of the env var changed at some point - it used to be called `DB_USER`, but is now called `DB_USERNAME`, so check that your .env file reflects the correct var name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this exact same problem for the past few days and I think I solved it:

The settings in `.env` are not always used for some reason or other and occasionally Laravel will just use the default settings in `config/app.php` and `config/database.php`.

`config/app.php`:

```php
// Change the 'SomeRandomString' to the generated key from your .env
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),
 
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

`config/database.php`

```php
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Change `localhost`, `database`, `username`, `password` to your actual settings from the `.env`.

This example is for `MySQL` if you use another database engine, change to those variables instead.

There might be a better solution (more secure?) but this is what so far kept the error from showing up.

Comment: This seems to be the case. But why this exactly happens? Do you have any idea how to debug this? I'd like to get rid of there messages in log files without overwriting default values in `database.php`

Comment: i think that this is a decent workaround, so either way, it will use the intended variables. `[+1]`

Answer (score 4):

In a multithreaded webserver two instances of PHP will share the same environment variables. That's a problem, because process A may shut down and set its ENV variables to null while process B is running, then when process B is asking for a ENV variable it will return null, that's why env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge') will sometimes result in forge, and other times the correct ENV.

More info [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24510#issuecomment-395865724), [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24510#issuecomment-494074690) and [here](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/76#issue-64818663)

One solution is to stop running a threaded web server (even if you compile with thread safety [PHP might run functions that are not thread safe](https://mattallan.me/posts/how-php-environment-variables-actually-work/).)

But a quick and simple fix to your issue is by running:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

That will cache your ENV and config which avoids the issue (laravel will not be calling getenv/putenv when configs are cached). The downside is you have to run this command anytime you make a change in your environment variables or configs.

Another solution I found is to place this line in your bootstrap/app.php file:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Env::disablePutenv();
```

Comment: I would never put `\Illuminate\Support\Env::disablePutenv();` because it will slow your app down and cause issues in your production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for others out there:
In my case, the .env file was not readable for the php user. So changing the .env file to public read-only fixed it (`chmod 664`).

Answer (score 1):

This problem still exists until now.

For me the solution was: `php artisan config:clear` & `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Recaching the config was the fix for me, even though I'm pretty sure it's not recommended to do in development.

Answer (score 0):

none of the above did it for me but it has helped me figuring out that only my APP_ENV env variable was not loaded.

In my case above issue has occurred when running a fresh migration after upgrading Laravel from v6 > v8. One of the oAuth migrations (create_oauth_auth_codes_table) is somehow failing to access APP_ENV and defaults to a "forge" mysql user which like @Grzegorz said is defined nowhere appart from within the oauth lib.

For security reasons I am quite reluctant to hard code default credentials in config/database.php and it being clear text in my git repo.

I have replicated the MySQL details env vars without the environment appended in .env like this

before:

```
DB_HOST_TESTING=127.0.0.1;unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
DB_DATABASE_TESTING=api
DB_USERNAME_TESTING=ubuntu
DB_PASSWORD_TESTING=***************
```

after

```
DB_HOST_TESTING=127.0.0.1;unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
DB_DATABASE_TESTING=api
DB_USERNAME_TESTING=ubuntu
DB_PASSWORD_TESTING=***************

# duplicate details without env appended
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1;unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
DB_DATABASE=api
DB_USERNAME=ubuntu
DB_PASSWORD=***************
```

I don't like having to do this either but I hope it will help someone.