# Laravel 8 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm working with Laravel, and everything is fine so far. But sometimes, when I request a webpage, an error occurs :

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I don't understand why and when this error occurs, it seems very random (~1%), and reloading the page fix it.
My .env file looks like this :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=docfus
DB_USERNAME=my_username
DB_PASSWORD=obviously_azerty
```

Where does this user 'forge' come from ? I never had one, I don't understand why is Laravel looking for it.

Note : I'm saying that this error seems to be random because I use Ajax to load some subPage in my main page. And sometimes one of theses elements fail to load with this error, but not everytimes and not always the same.

Edit : I tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` but I still get the error times to times.

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan cache:clear` then try again

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan config:clear` is your friend ;) `forge` is default database name and username and it's part of database.php in config. There is possibility that you cache config files before setting up environment in .env file

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why should this help to resolve a pretty random database authentication error?

Comment: I thought that worked, but the error is back again. Didn't mention it, but my project is more than 200hours old, so I don't think this error is linked to old cached files.

Comment: i solved mine using the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235926/laravel-access-denied-for-user-forgelocalhost-but-no-such-user-is-used-in).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved with the following:

1. delete all files under \bootstrap\cache. I was using xampp, so this was my folder 'C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\cache'
2. php artisan optimize